# Ruby - Interpolate text quickly in regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string

We know this:

```
p '%s' % "test"
#=> "test"
```

But is it possible to do this:

```
s = "string"
s[/#{%s}/] % "test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could always just do this:

```
s[Regexp.new("%s" % "test")]
```

If your string can contain characters with special meaning, use `Regexp.escape` beforehand. Also, you can directly interpolate into a regular expression:

```
s = "test"
/#{s}/ #=> /test/
```